# canShowCallout button doesn't work

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, mkmapview

I think i there is something wrong in my Code but i cannot find it.

I want to switch the view with a single click on the `leftCalloutAccessoryView` button but i receive always the same error:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '
-[ThirdViewController showDetailView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Here my Code:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        return nil;
    }
    else
    {
        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"loc"];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        UIButton *detailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

        [detailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetailView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView=detailButton;
        annotationView.enabled = YES;

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.jpeg"];
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = imgView;
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin.png"];
        return annotationView;
    }
}
- (IBAction)detailButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    ThirdViewController *infoView = [[ThirdViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:infoView animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"pushed Button!!!!!!");

}
```

little screenshot from my Storyboard:

[image]

Thank your for the help!

Best regards CTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `addTarget`, the code says the button should call the method `showDetailView:`:

```
[detailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetailView:) forControlEvents...
```

But there is no such method (that's what the error means).

Change this method's name from:

```
- (IBAction)detailButton:(UIButton *)sender
```

to:

```
- (IBAction)showDetailView:(UIButton *)sender
```